Проблема с (tabs) на React Native (Expo)
В проекте React native (expo) я использую встроенный роутинг от expo-router я создал app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx в котором я хочу сделать чтобы вкладка избранное не отображалось в tabs (нижней строке), если пользователь не авторизован:
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useAuth } from '../auth/AuthProvider';

export default function TabLayout() {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'blue',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        tabBarLabelStyle: styles.tabLabel,
      }}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen name="index" options={{
        title: 'Фильмы',
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="film" size={24} color={color} />
        ),
      }} />
      {user && (
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="favorites"
          options={{
            title: 'Избранное',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <Ionicons name="heart" size={24} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      )}
    </Tabs>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabLabel: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

в таком примере приложение выдает ошибку:

WARN  Layout children must be of type Screen, all other children are
ignored. To use custom children, create a custom . Update
Layout Route at: "app/(tabs)/_layout" [Component Stack]

Такой вариант тоже не работает:
  <Tabs.Screen name="favorites" options={{
    title: 'Избранное',
    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
      <Ionicons name="heart" size={24} color={color} />
    ),
    tabBarStyle: user ? {} : { display: 'none' },
    tabBarIconStyle: user ? {} : { display: 'none' },
    tabBarShowLabel: user ? true : false,
  }}
  />

При таком варианте скрывается только иконка, но остается текст "Избранное", а так же необходимо сделать чтобы первый элемент Tab screen растягивался и оставался один пока пользователь не авторизован.
